# Best way to do some math

Tags: php, sql, math

i am making a web app and i need to get two variables convert then subtract them from each other to get the elapsed time here is what i currently have.

```
public function Cycle() {
  $conn = odbc_connect('monitor', '', '');
    if (!$conn) {
        exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
    }
    $sql = "         SELECT TOP 2 ReaderData.ReaderIndex, ReaderData.CardID,                     ReaderData.ReaderDate, ReaderData.ReaderTime, ReaderData.controllerID, Left([dtReading],10) AS [date], ReaderData.dtReading FROM ReaderData WHERE ReaderData.controllerID=$this->Id ORDER BY ReaderData.ReaderIndex desc;";
    $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
    if (!$rs) {
        exit("Error in SQL");
    }

    while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
        $this->DtReading = odbc_result($rs, "dtReading");


echo $this->DtReading." ";

    }
     odbc_close($conn);
}
```

currently this Outputs the two rows that i need, so what would be the best way to take the variable DtReading from each row and store them in separate variables so i can do things with them?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the values into an array:

```
$data=array();

while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
    $data[] = $this->DtReading = odbc_result($rs, "dtReading");
}

$result = $data[0] - $data[1];
```